# Can the value of indefinite integrals $\int f(x)dx$ be evaluated?

Tags: calculus, integration, functions, notation

When I was taught about indefinite integrals we are given equalities like

$$\int f(x)dx=e^x+c$$ where $c$ is a parameter.

If we use a parameter like in $g(x)=e^x+c$

We can usually say:

For
$c=1$ and $x=2$

$g(x)=e^x+c$

$g(x)=e^2$

However it seems strange to say that:

For $c=1$

$\int f(x)dx=e^x+1$

or if $x=2$,$c=1$.

$\int f(x)dx=e^2$

When we are given indefinite integrals we usually just use the 'form', i.e that we have

$\int f(x)dx=e^x+c$

Are the occurences of the variables done in a way that they cannot be evaluated in the same way, so when we calculate the indefinite integral we are looking for the form of the expression.

If we have a function $f$ and variable $x$, and constant $c$ would it be correct to say that we use the integral notation to refer to the form of $F(x)$ where $F'(x)=f(x)$ without considering it's 'evaluation'? hence why we often give different integrals their own constant of integration.

Comment: $\int f(x) \, \mathrm{d}x$ is just a shorthand for the antiderivative of $f$, and writing $+c$ is a reminder to students that antiderivatives (on connected domains) are only unique up to a constant. I wouldn't read more into that.

Comment: I simply don't undertand the question. For a given integrable function $f$, there are infinitely many functions $F$ such that $F'=f$. Moreover, if $F'_1=F'_2$ then $F_1-F_2$ is constant. So if you what to evaluate $F$ in a given point, you need the point and the constant, roughly speaking. In your post, for $c=1$ and $x= 2$ you get $g(x)=e^2+1$.

Comment: @ajotatxe precisely, but in that case $\int f(x)dx=F(x)$ so  $\int f(x)dx$ should have it's value determined by $x$ and $c$ but that doesn't seem correct.

Comment: I don't understand why you write that “if $x=2$, $\int f(x)\,\mathrm dx=e^2$”. Since $\int f(x)\,\mathrm dx=e^x+c$, if $x=2$ then you should get $e^2+c$.

Comment: @JoséCarlosSantos corrected it

Answer (score 1):

Maybe it helps to think of the indefinite integral as neither a value nor a function, but a set of antiderivative functions.

$$ \int f(x)\, dx = \{ F: \mathbb{R} \to \mathbb{R} \mid F' = f \} $$

So any function whose derivative $F'(x)$ equals $f(x)$ at every $x$ is a member of this set. If $f(x) = e^x$, then functions $F_1(x) = e^x$, $F_2(x) = e^x+1$, and $F_3(x) = e^x-\pi$ are all in the set. Usually we'll just write this as the general form of all these functions:

$$ \int e^x\, dx = e^x + C $$

If you want to be extremely technical, you might object to how "$=$" is used here, as it's not exactly saying two things are the same. But we do have other uses of the symbol $=$ that don't actually mean that: for example, "$\lim_{x \to a} f(x) = +\infty$" has a specific meaning as an equation in plain real analysis, even though the limit on the left and $+\infty$ on the right are not real numbers.

Comment: So an indefinite integral is more of a set? The use of equals sign here is more informal in this case? So 'evaluating' the indefinite integral at $(x,c)$ is not something that we do? I also notice we use different constants of integration which makes sense as any constant of integration can form the set.